# How to disable case sensitivities in MySQL by a run time script in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I had to import a MySQL backup from a Windows server to a Linux server. As table names were in both upper and lower case in the previous database, I have problem right now because in current server (Linux) settings are case insensitive mode for MySQL. Also I can not change its settings because it's a shared hosting and I dont have access to it.
How can I force MySQL to run in case insensitive mode using a run time script in PHP?

Comment: Change your PHP script to use consistent table names. And better have some established convention (e.g. always use lowercase letters in table names). Edit the dump file appropriately (or do the changes before the dump).

Comment: This setting cannot be changed at run time. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html .

Comment: @DCoder surely that is an answer?

Comment: Run a MySQL proxy between the PHP MySQL client and MySQL server? Something like [MySQL Router 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/0) or [ProxySQL](https://www.proxysql.com/) , do some scripting/rules on SQL parsing that the table names are always lowercase for example.. Well the shared hosting does not make it more easy so you might need to be looking for something which runs in PHP code ..

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this code for rename that or use on the fly:

```
select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ' , lower(table_name) , ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';

SELECT * from lower(table_name) ...
```

Answer (score -3):

Resolving this is actually very simple. All you need to do is edit the my.cnf file and set/add the following entry. For my default mysql install "my.cnf" was located at "c:\program files\mysql\mysql server[version]\my.cnf"

```
#Ensure that table names are stored case sensitive and that queries are case sensitive when naming a table
lower_case_table_names=0
```

you can change this path to gnu/linux

Comment: But OP says `I can not change its settings because its a shared hosting ` . Also, your solution refers to a Windows install, and just saying "change to a linux path" doesn't give many clues on _where_ and _how_ make this changes on a linux environment